# Como hacer un login en Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, cshtml

Mi problema más que todo se define en 3 interrogantes
1) Como obtengo los valores de los Html.textboxfor()
2)Como le paso mi método Login al botón de inicio de sesión para que haga la lógica de dicho método
3)Como retorno la vista en dado caso que la validación sea correcta?

Perdonen si creen que parezca un poco estúpido preguntar cosas tan fáciles pero mis conocimientos en asp.net mvc son pocos y me gustaría aprender. Lo que he hecho ha sido crear un metodo action result en el controlador "Acceso" que contiene la logica del login [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lei en internet que podias obtener los valores del textboxfor con request.form .

Luego comencé a crear un modelo llamado "Acceso" que contiene una clase para el login

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y Despues diseñe el html del Login pero no tengo ni la más remota idea de como poder conectar todo eso al boton de iniciar sesion ni como obtener los valores de los textbox for .[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme con esto. Es mi primer post en stack overflow asi que realmente lamento molestarlos con esto. Muchisimas gracias

Comment: Hubiera estado bueno si ponias el codigo como texto y no como imagenes, o al menos de las dos formas

Answer (score -1):

Para recibir los valores debes hacer un `submit` del `form` al action que defines como `HttpPost` de esta forma entra en juego el `model binding`

No necesitas del `Request.Form[]` para tomar los datos, si tienes un Model lo usas de esta forma

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model){
    //resto codigo

    return RedirectToAction("xx", "xx");
}
```

si pasa bien el login lo redireccionas a la pagina principal

Si las propiedades que usas en los `Html.TextBoxForm()` son de la clase model en el post se recibiran y maparan con el modleo que defines en el parametro del action

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Leando, me fue muy util y aclaró algunas dudas que tenia, ¿Como puedo? hacer un submit del form? De nuevo muchisimas gracias por responderme